# laravel retrieving the database config to use in a package config

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have my database config in

```
app/config/database.php
and
app/config/development/database.php
```

now I installed a new package that needs access to the same info 'host,username,password' and is located in

```
app/config/packages/pkg/database.php
```

How can I programatically get this information and conditionally set it in this databases.php?

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => ?,
        'database'  => ?,
        'username'  => ?,
```

Comment: If the package is registered correctly, you could use `Config::get('pkg::mysql.driver');` to get that info. However, `Config::set` only sets the values in run-time (current request), is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can instance a object using the facade pattern of laravel, like this:

`Config:get('database.array.of.content');`